# How to feed fake time to an android app?

Tags: android, time

I'd like to know, can I feed fake time to a certain app?
If I have the X app for example, can I create a Y app, that ensures that when the X app checks the time, it will receive the current time plus certain amount?

Cheers

Comment: There might be a different way of doing this.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: On Linux proper you have libfaketime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate system clock normally.

On a rooted device you could try with [SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#setCurrentTimeMillis%28long%29), but that's global for all applications.